# Acumatica 6.0 Wiki Publish returning error

Tags: acumatica

Every time I'm trying to publish Customization with Wiki page in it the Acumatica Customization Publish Engine is returning error :

> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

There is no mistake in the Customization and the Wiki page is correctly created and bonded.
The only thing that I'm thinking can be the reason is that some table indexes were corrupted while updating the System from 5.3 to 6.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was in `WikiRevesion` and `SearchIndex` tables. They were corrupted while updating **Acumatica ERP** from **5.3** version to **6.00**. The solution was to run the following SQL Query:

```
use YOUR_SYSTEM_DATABASE_NAME
go
UPDATE dbo.WikiRevision SET UID = NEWID()
UPDATE dbo.SearchIndex SET IndexID = NEWID()
```